# Error with APK but not running : app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: (...)

Tags: android

I've an Error when I want to make an apk with my app (I put everything, in case it could help you to solve my problem...) :

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAds1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\Espremea\Documents\Longest game ever\app\google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode.class

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The problem only occures when I'm building the APK, not during the build nor the direct run with an emulator or my phone.

Here is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "course.examples.longestgameever"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I really don't know what to do and didn't find anything online that worked for me. Thanks for your help :) !

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire output of your Gradle Console. The source of your problem lies somewhere above the line that you quoted in your question.

Comment: I changed it and put everything (maybe too much), hope it helps, thanks :)

Comment: `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode.class` -- my guess is that you should remove the `compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar')` line, as I think that conflicts with `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'`.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem... :s
"(...)
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode.class" Same as before I think ^^'

Comment: You should also get rid of that JAR entirely, or move it out of `libs/`, as it will get picked up by your `compile fileTree()` statement. Then, clean your project (Build > Clean Project), and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! =)